# Making the bar code scanner more adaptive

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I made a barcode scanner using the zxing library. However, I need to incorporate specific functionalities, like the camera detecting the bar code(live) and enclose it in a rectangle.
Also to intuitively direct the user to shift the camera so that the procedure is not much of a burden.
Is it advisable to turn on the phone torch(flash) while detecting? If yes,how can it be done to the exact amount of light required for successful scanning, at that moment of time?